# Check any celleditor in a data table is in edit mode

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a data table displying some application parameters having 3 columns: 
name (outputext), 
value (p:cellEditor) and 
edit (p:rowEditor used)

On clicking edit button in any row value field converts into input field and is having validator attached. After changing and accepting( clicking check icon) values an 'update button' is provided at the bottom of page to save all changes.

My problem is if a validation error comes and we press 'update button' then call goes to save function in managed bean with old value. So to stop this I want to disable 'update button' when any row is  having edit mode opened. Can I check the mode of all cell editors in column 2 , so I will use that in disabled attribute of update button.
Please do suggest any other better way is also possible ?

Using a jsf 2.1 and primefaces 3.5

XHTML snippet

```
        <!-- Body panel for display of individual configuration mode -->
        <p:panel id="mainConfigPanel" >
        <!-- status message section -->
        <p:messages id="msg" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
        <!-- Parameter configuration mode -->
            <p:panel
                rendered="#{configMBean.configUtility.configParamModeOn}"
                styleClass="panelNoBorder">
                <p:dataTable id="configParamTable" var="configParamVar"
                    value="#{configMBean.configParamList}" editable="true">

                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{configMBean.onRowEdit}" update=":mainForm:msg" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{configMBean.onRowCancel}"  update=":mainForm:msg" />

                    <p:column headerText="Parameter Name" sortBy="#{configParamVar.paramConfigName}">
                        <h:outputText id="paramNameId" value="#{configParamVar.paramConfigName}" />
                    </p:column>


                    <p:column headerText="Param Value" sortBy="#{configParamVar.paramConfigValue}">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output" > <h:outputText value="#{configParamVar.paramConfigValue}" /> </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText id="paramValueId" value="#{configParamVar.paramConfigValue}" required="true"
                                    validator="#{configMBean.validateParam}"   >
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="2000" />
                                    <f:attribute name="input" value="#{configParamVar}" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Edit" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:20px">
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>


                <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
                    <p:commandButton value="Update Parameters" actionListener="#{configMBean.saveParamUpdate}" update=":mainForm" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{configMBean.cancelParamUpdate}" immediate="true" update=":mainForm">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
            <!-- End of Parameter configuration mode panel -->


</p:panel>
<!-- End of body panel for individual configuration mode -->

    </p:panelGrid>
    <!-- end of main panel -->
```

Functions in Managed Bean

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    System.out.println(" In Row Edit");
}

public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    System.out.println("In Row Canel of Parameter Config");
}

public void validateParam(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException, Exception {
    if (value != null) {
        //Getting  parameter Name and Value for validation
        String paramName = ((RowEntity) component.getAttributes().get("input")).getParamConfigName();
        String paramValue = (String) value;
        FacesMessage msg = null;

        //Validation Cases
        if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase(ResourceBundle.getMsg("Param_Enable_FTP"))) {
            if (!paramValue.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || !paramValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, ResourceBundle.getMsg("Param_True_False_Validation")+ paramName, "");
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        } else if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase(ResourceBundle.getMsg("Param_Contingency_Reserve"))) {
            if (!Pattern.matches("-?\\d*\\.?\\d*", paramValue)) {
                    msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, ResourceBundle.getMsg("Param_Number_Validation") + paramName, "");
                    throw new ValidatorException(msg);
                }
        }// end if else if

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I got you right. Why do you use for the same row a cellEditor AND a rowEditor? Why don't you use a rowEditor for all columns which can be updated? So you wouldn't need a save button. Probably you provide some code to your question. Much easier for everyone to get into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: There is an Ajax Behavior Event for `rowEdit`

```
rowEdit | org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent | When a row is edited.
```

You could disable the update button when the `RowEditEvent` got fired and release the button after the row editing was canceled or saved.

I Hope I got your question right and this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If validation fails a ValidatorException is thrown so program does not reaches rowEdit event to toggle the Update Button.
Something is required before rowEdit Event

Comment: I suppose you use a custom FacesValidator for your datatable. That means you could disable/enable the button in your validation, couldn't you?

Comment: Yes, I tried it putting disabled condition in when validation fails and in RowEdit and RowCancel - I have added enabling condition.
It works but as enable code is written in rowEdit and rowCancel, in below scenario there is a little problem.  

Validation error occurs in first row and it disables the button, after this if I go to second row and make change and accept it (rowEdit of second row fires) update button gets enabled.

Therefore if I have some way to check if any row is in edit Mode/ having exception I will keep update button disabled and vice-versa.

Comment: You could prevent multiple row editing... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376811/primefaces-datatable-roweditor-only-permit-one-row-editting
I think it would make more sense to update records one by one.

Comment: Yes this is possible way to achieve above goal.
Thanks for your help :)