# Complex Primefaces datatable slow loading on client side

Tags: performance, jsf, primefaces, datatable, time-complexity

I have a lazy datatable with 40 complex editabe columns (most of them have autocomplete, calendar and selectOneMenu components) plus sorting and filtering...  and it's taking too much time to load.

I'm using pagination and I noticed that when I select 10 rows by default, the time to load on the browser seems pretty decent. But if I choose 50 rows, changing from one page to the other takes around 13 seconds in the best cases (yes I know, it's 40 complex columns and 50 rows... ).

At first I thought the time complexity was on the server side, because of the complex query it executes each time you apply a filter or change page, but I measured it and the time it takes to query the DB is basically irrelevant compared with the amount of seconds it takes to load.Even more, I checked the perfomance on Chrome and almost 60% of the time is dedicated to 'Scripting' according to the performance tester (I don't really understand all the process of loading the page onto the browser, but I'll trust them about that).

So, my question is... 
Am I missing something crucial about performance here? Is there something I can still do from the code in order to improve the loading time? My client's requirements led me into this solution and I cannot sacrifice ant functionalities... So the components in every column, the number of columns and the number of rows per page are non-negotiable. I hope you can give me some hint about it since I'm having serious claims about the response times and don't really know what to do. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately you are trying to use the datatable for editing a form which I am not a fan of because of this issue of making your page have a TON of HTML in it. You have two choices 1) use Datatable row editing which only will display 1 row of editable fields at a time:https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml or use the PrimeFaces Extension Sheet component if you truly need Excel like editing: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf

Comment: Thanks for you response. The Sheet extension really surprised me ... didn't know about it, thanks for that hint. About 1), what do you mean exactly? I'm using row edition (not cell edit) but don't get your idea yet..

Comment: About the 'idea', check the generated html for both cases in the PrimeFaces showcase. The one with rowediting has waaaay less complex html (and thus is faster)

Comment: @Kukeltje but I dont understand how to achieve the 'one editable at a time' thing. If you take a look into the showcase, you see that the 'row edit' mode allows you to edit multiple rows concurrently. How can I achieve the restriction of allowing the edit of just one row in order to improve performance? Am I being to slow to get something trivial here?

Comment: It is not the restriction to 1 per say, that increases performance but rather that by default no row is rendered as editable. Putting a row in edit mode and than one more is not a performance killer. If you want to just have maximum one row in edit mode, that is a new question which is btw an existing one in Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376811/primefaces-datatable-roweditor-only-permit-one-row-editing

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm actually using row edit mode, but in my datatable every column has a cellEditor which is rendered for every row. I don't understand why you say that using row edit mode no row will be rendered as editable. The only way I can think of in order to achieve that is adding a rendered="false" to every cellEditor... but I'm not seeing that happening by default. I'm not a PF senior and I understand that I'm probably ommiting something here.. please be patient with me :P

Comment: @Kukeltje in case you mean using the 'rowEditMode=lazy' (something I just discovered) that is no possible since I'm using PF 6.2 and it's not available in my datatable options.

Comment: Yes, then update... Or download the source of 6.2 and 7 and patch your 6.2 version (see why mentioning version info upfront is always a good thing!)

Comment: That's right, thank you a lot for your help! I'll try to update.

Comment: Any progress/feedback?

Comment: @Kukeltje I found out the problem was due to the fact that the server will render 50 cellEditors (one for every row) and that makes the page so heavy that the browser will hang a little in order to load it. Since I'm restricted to stay in PF 6.2 I figured out a way to avoid this situation by just conditioning the rendering of all the cellEditors, and update/re-render a single row when it is selected by the user, in which case the cellEditor gets rendered (condition #{bean.selectedRow eq rowVar} evals to true ) and it worked.  Should I answer my own question with code examples?

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry but I didn't know how to do the "dowload the code and patch it" thing... kind of a newbie here...although the answers in this post were considerably helpful and helped a lot to see where the problem was ..